# Проверка наличия обновления для переменной

Tags: java, android, c

В общем, нужно как-то проверить переменную на её старое значение. Т.е: если переменная равна старому значению - ничего не делать, если же новому - что-то начать делать. Пример:

```
int a;
int b;

if (a!=b)

//что-то сделать
```

a и b - принимают, по сути, одно и то же значение, но переменная a - может изменяться, по этому нужно как-то проверить, как она изменилась и если она не равна прежнему значению - то нужно что-то сделать. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил

Comment: Ну сохраните старое значение и проверяйте. Проблема-то в чем?

Comment: Как?) Просто ещё не особо разбираюсь в программировании)

Comment: Так у вас уже готовый код висит вверху, который вы и написали. Вы сначала определитесь с тем, какие действия нужно выполнить, если переменные не равны - а потом и спрашивайте. А то не понятно что вы хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но если вопрос в проверке старого значения и никто не запрещает создать новую переменную, то:

```
int a,aOld=a;


//где-то у вас в коде:
if(a!=aOld){
aOld=a;
//что-то ещё сделать
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать метод, который будет возвращать текущее значение переменной, и метод, который будет присваивать значение переменной. Во 2м методе, после присвоения нового значения переменной Вы будете выполнять различные проверки и т.д.

Comment: А в Си разве можно использовать классы?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch упс, почему-то написал на C#... Сейчас исправил ответ, теперь он является универсальным для любого ЯП.